# Silex and doctrine orm mapping - no mappings detected

Tags: orm, doctrine, silex

I have a problem with setting up entities mapping in silex app.

Registering services:

```php
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider(), array(
    'db.options' => array(
        'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
        'dbname'   => 'blabla',
        'host'     => 'blabla',
        'user'     => 'blabla',
        'password' => 'blabla',
        'port'     => '3306',
        'charset'  => 'utf8'
    ),
));

$app->register(new DoctrineOrmServiceProvider(), [
    'orm.em.options.mappings' => [
            [
                'type' => 'simple_yml',
                'namespace' => 'App\Entities',
                'path' => __DIR__. '/Resources/orm/mappings/',
            ],
    ]
]);
```

*src/Resources/orm/mappings/User.orm.yml*:

```
User:
  type: entity
  table: users
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    username:
      type: string
    email:
      type: string
    github_token:
      type: string
    github_token_created_at:
      type: datetimetz
    created_at:
      type: datetimetz
    updated_at:
      type: datetimetz
```

And entity class itself is in: *src/Entities/User.php*

*cli-config.php* file:

```php
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once 'src/app.php';

return \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($app['orm.em']);
```

And I am running following command:

`vendor/bin/doctrine orm:info`

I am getting info about lack of mappings:

```
 [Exception]                                                                                                                                                                            
  You do not have any mapped Doctrine ORM entities according to the current configuration. If you have entities or mapping files you should check your mapping configuration for errors`
```

I am 99% sure paths are set up ok, the connection to database is correct, I have no idea why it doesn't work. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Most mappings i've seen are like this

```
    'mappings' => array(
        // Using actual filesystem paths
        array(
            'type' => 'annotation',
            'namespace' => 'Foo\Entities',
            'path' => __DIR__.'/src/Foo/Entities',
        ),
```

You do not seem to have your namespace and path in any notable relationship

Comment: Because I don't use annotations. Namespace is for entities and path is for where yml files are.

Comment: i've not attempted this configuration. Have you checked that your autoloading is working?

Comment: Autoloading is working. I dumped the $app['orm.em'] object in cli-config.php file. There was an instance. There's no class not found messages etc.

Comment: can you show me line of code you use to do the autoloading?

Comment: Can you just specify what exactly autoloading you think about? I was thinking just about composer one.

Comment: yes the line where you are adding your own namespace please

Comment: look at https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/282 try using psr-0 setup you may perhaps have more success!

Comment: I changed to PSR-0 but it did not do the trick. Still, exactly same issue.